# Joomla custom template error installing

Tags: xml, joomla, joomla-template

I've done a simple template for Joomla 3.6.4 but when I try to install it to my Apache server, it's returning an error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''0','Template fuer emir - Default','{}')' at line 3 SQL=INSERT INTO `#__template_styles` (`template`,`client_id`,`home`,`title`,`params`) VALUES ('template',,'0','Template - Default','{}')
```

templateDetails.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE install PUBLIC "-//Joomla! 2.5//DTD template 1.0//EN"
"http://www.joomla.org/xml/dtd/1.6/template-install.dtd">
<extension version="3.6" type="template" client="side">
  <name>template</name>
  <creationDate>05. jan 2017</creationDate>
  <author>[myname]</author>
  <authorEmail>[mymail]</authorEmail>
  <version>1.0</version>

  <description>Template</description>
  <files>
    <folder>img</folder>
    <file>index.php</file>
    <file>index.css</file>
    <file>templateDetails.xml</file>
  </files>
  <positions>
    <position>header</position>
    <position>navbar</position>
    <position>debug</position>
    <position>footer</position>
  </positions>
</extension>
```

I have no idea what the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to change `client="side"` into `client="site"`.